# Emacs + whitespace: ignoring 'normal' spaces

Tags: emacs, whitespace

I would like to use whitespace to detect wrong whitespace (i.e. trailing whitespace on line, tabs instead of spaces etc.).

However I would like to still have spaces displayed as spaces. I tried to use `whitespace-space` variable but I have not managed to do it. Is it possible? How to do it?

Answer (score 2):

What Whitespace mode displays is controlled by the `whitespace-style` variable. Remove `spaces` from that list. You can do it from the Customize interface (Convenience / Whitespace / Whitespace Style) or by hand:

```
(eval-after-load "whitespace" '(setq whitespace-style (delq 'spaces whitespace-style)))
```